# Why do I get I/O error when zipping a file in Ubuntu s3fs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, zip, s3fs

I have a s3fs mounted in a filesystem in Ubuntu. Often when i zip large files, i an error below:

zip I/O error: Input/output error
zip error: Temporary file failure (zivyOwPF)
free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you give some more specific instructions to reproduce this behavior?  The double free comes from zip itself which is a pretty wild error.  Unless s3fs is returning some bogus data and zip does not handle bad input correctly.

Comment: Hi Andrew, i mounted a s3 bucket using s3fs to my Ubuntu 18.x machine and i go inside a prefix from Ubuntu CLI and zip it (the file is 5GB+) and it throws an error. #zip -v -r -dc TestZipFile7 Day\=20211012 --> throws error as : zip I/O error: Input/output error
zip error: Temporary file failure (zivyOwPF)
free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Comment: Could you share the exact command line and roughly the numbers and sizes of files? this appears to be a bug within zip itself that I will investigate. If you can run zip under Valgrind it will help me.